# HTML— Create horizontal Scrollbar once a certain width has been reached

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, overflow

I have a horizontal navbar with width 100%. Once the nav has reached a certain
minimum width— around 800px, I say,— I'd like a horizontal scrollbar to appear. The CSS property min-width doesn't work because it does not create a scroll bar.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720017/horizontal-scrollbar-past-the-min-width-point) post asks the same question as mine does, but the only good answer that the person got is to utilize a jQuery plugin, and I'm not certain how to add a scrollbar using it.

How can I add horizontal scrollbars past a fixed min-width? Please help me out.

Thanks.

**EDIT** As requested, here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<nav id="topBar">
    <section id="topBarRight">
        <!-- stuff !-->
    </section>
</nav>
```

**CSS** (without any of your suggestions)

```
#topBar
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 800px;
}

#topBarRight
{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In essence, you need some kind of parent element to contain the navigation, acting as a kind of "viewport":

```html
<nav id="topBar">
  <section id="topBarRight">
    <ul id="navMenu">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Then you can constrain the width of the parent and allow the navigation to grow as wide as necessary:

```
<style>
  #topBar {
    /* ... */
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  #topBarRight {
    min-width: 800px;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }

  #navMenu {
    float: right;
    /* ... */
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what content you have in `#topBarRight`, so I just stuck a `<ul>` in there. I was able to get scroll bars on `#topBar` by setting its width to 100% and setting the `min-width` on `#topBarRight`. I'll update my answer again.

Comment: Tried it, but the scrollbar is vertical.

Comment: I copied and pasted my example code directly into an HTML document, opened it in WebKit, and got horizontal scroll bars to appear when I shrunk the browser window width below 800px. What are the contents of `#topBarRight`? Which browser are you using?

Comment: I have a WebKit browser, too: Chrome. The code inside #topBarRight is just some navigational links. I'll look into it, thanks for your support.

Comment: The horizontal scrollbar appears when needed, but now there's **always** a little vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Also, this setup has proven to be ugly and unreliable for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I'd place a div with min-width as parent of all navbar contents into the navbar.
The navbar itself should then have overflow-x:auto and overflow-y:hidden, or overflow:auto.
The scrollbar will require additional vertical space, so the vertical scrollbar may be required too.

Comment: You mean min-width instead of minSize?

Answer (score 1):

This makes a box with a static width to contain your content. When there is not enough room to contain the box (window is < 400px) a scrollbar appears.
http://jsfiddle.net/Re4AP/5/

This makes a box that is 100% width by default with a min-width of 400px to contain your content. When there is not enough room to contain the content in the box it breaks the content (text in this case) onto multiple lines. If the window is less than 400px (the min width), a scrollbar appears.
 http://jsfiddle.net/Re4AP/7/

Comment: Does the fiddle illustrate what you were asking about?

Comment: Not really. If I set the width property to the min-width, then the navbar is obviously going to be too small when the window is LARGER than the min-width. However, the overflow was handled as I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You said, "Once the nav has reached a certain minimum width, I'd like a horizontal scrollbar to appear". I am confused about this. What do you mean by a minimum width? Clarify what you want to achieve please.

Comment: Sorry about that. As a window gets smaller, the navbar gets smaller, too, because its width is in percentages. However, once the window is 800 pixels or smaller, it just isn't enough to contain all the stuff that's inside the navbar. The minimum width for the navbar to function properly is therefore 800 px. After that, a scrollbar should appear.

Comment: Would I need to set the width of #navbar to 800px?

Comment: Set it to whatever you want. I'm still not sure if you need width or min-width so I updated with 2 fiddles - hopefully one of these is close to what you want.